# How do I tell Suave not to cache a url?

Tags: suave

I have 2 paths getting cached

```
Auth.loggedOn (
    GET >=>
        pathScan "/era/%i" (Some >> EraViewing.eraView homeFolder cn)
        path "/" >=> indexView homeFolder cn
```

There is a `x.html` file behind each of these which get served after replacing some templated parts.

Which are getting cached, but I do not want them to. how can I tell suave not ?

---

Not [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931078/suave-control-when-responses-are-cached-or-recalculated), as that one is solved by making something a function rather than telling suave not to cache or when to recalcuate/reevaluate a url

Comment: I seem to have skipped the `choose [` line that should be below line 2 but I think it's pretty clear otherwise

Comment: Do you mean the response is being cached by browser ?

Comment: well, when I run with browser cache disabled, it appears to show that is the case. how do I handle that in suave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To indicate the browser to not cache the response you can define the following combinator.

```
let noCache = 
  setHeader "Cache-Control" "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  >=> setHeader "Pragma" "no-cache"
  >=> setHeader "Expires" "0"
```

And use it like in the following

```
let app = OK "Hello" >=> noCache
```